# Postgres and data folder changing on Windows

Tags: postgresql

It is possible to change postgres data folder during its installation on Windows? For example run the postgres instalator with some parameter.
At this time Iam using this procedure: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_the_default_PGDATA_directory_on_Windows
Or is there another script which do that?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you are prompted to enter/select the data directory during installation.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: So what's your question then? Just specify an alternate location during installation.

Comment: Than you horse for discussion. I wanted to order my mind.

Comment: Than you horse for discussion. I wanted to order my mind. I found exe postgres parameter -D datadir which do what I want. In my first post I forgot to say thah I use installation in silent mode and using parameters for configuration.